# Adding a class dynamically to hide only yield part of the ember component without wrapping

Tags: ember.js, components

Is there any way to add a class(In my case it is **hide** class) dynamically to hide(**display : none**) only ***yield*** part of the ember component **without wrapping** the yield part of the component with **tags** (div,span or anyother) in Ember JS?

My Case :

```
 {{#if isLoading}}
     <p>Loading....!</p>
 {{/if}}
 <div class="{{isLoading "hide"}}">
     {{yield}}
 </div>
```

Here I want to hide the yield part without wrapping it up by a **div** tag

**Note** : I can't use  **If Else statement**    as it will destroy the  current instance  of component every time   **isLoading**    property changes.    **This is a component to show loading. Any other ways to use a component for loading is appreciated**

Comment: You can't have a class without an element. `class` is an attribute of element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a class without specifying an element or a tag. If you want to add class name to the yield part, then wrapping it in a container is the only way.